# XEP 0280 get carbon Message Body with sleekxmpp

Tags: python, python-2.7, xmpp, xmppframework

i have create a small XMPP Client with the Python Framework sleekxmpp. I use the followind Code to create the Connection Class:

```
class Client(ClientXMPP):
    def __init__(self, jid, password):
        ClientXMPP.__init__(self, jid, password)
        self.register_plugin('xep_0280')
        self.add_event_handler("session_start", self.session_start)
        self.add_event_handler("message", self.message)
        self.add_event_handler("carbon_received", self.carbon_received)
        self.add_event_handler("carbon_sent", self.carbon_sent)
```

i get a callBack to the message or carbon class. In the message function i can get the Message body with msg["body"] but how can i can get the Message Body from the carbons Messages?

I try to get it on the same way as on the message funktion, but it only return an empty string. If i make a typeof msg["forwarded"] i got "" but i can't get the message body.

The callback Function I use:

```
def message(self, msg):
    sendMsg(msg["to"], msg["body"])
    print msg["body"]
def carbon_received(self, msg):
    print "carbon_received"
    #print type(msg['forwarded'])
    #print msg['forwarded']["stanza"]
    #print msg
def carbon_sent(self, msg):
    print "carbon_sent"
    #print type(msg['forwarded'])
    #print msg['forwarded']["stanza"]
    #print msg
```